# Ios data auto delete

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch

Does iOS automatically deletes document directory or library directory data when phone memory gets full?
Wanted to save application data so that it won't get deleted automatically in any case.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone OS do not delete data saved in document directory automatically in low memory case. So it is safe to save app data in document directory.

iPhone OS can clear cache/tmp folder in low memory case. So I suggest you to not to store the app specific important data in cache/tmp folder.